# Помогите пожалуйста, с адаптивной с версткой. Уже кончились идеи

Tags: css, adaptive-design

Помогите, пожалуйста, сверстать эту надпись в блоке. Я уже перепробовал все варианты(которых не так много, ибо учусь до сих пор. Как должно быть:
[image: Десктоп развертка]

[image: мобильная]

как я это попытался реализовать(возможно, я немного усложнил это действие из-за разноцветной надписи). Уже сломал себе весь мозг. Спасибо заранее.

```css
.main {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    background-color: #1B2E59;
    color: aliceblue;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
.center-body {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    /* width: fit-content; */
    /* height: 300px; */
    padding: -30px 250px;
    /* line-height: 20px; */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    }
.else {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px; left: -200px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 990px) {
.center-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: fit-content;
    padding: -30px 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.else {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px; left: -30px;
   }

}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&family=DM+Sans:opsz,wght@9..40,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class = 'main'>
<div class = 'center-body'>
            <p>
                <span class="green" style="color: #00E300">GREEN,</span> 
                <span class="green" style="color: white" >NATURAL, STRONG.</span>
            </p>
            <p>
                <span class = 'else'  style="color: #00E300;">WHAT ELSE?</span>
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: По этим двум картина непонятно как должен выглядеть промежуточный вариант. Когда три слова уже не влезают, но два ещё помещаются.

Comment: @AlexeyTen на 990px они еще влезают, потом у меня весь остальной интерфейс на мобильную развертку переключается